# Как правильно запустить SurfaceView в Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Совсем недавно начал осваивать фрагменты и графику и не до конца понимаю их логику.

У меня есть фрагмент, во фрагменте должен запускаться `DrawView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`. Сейчас это какие-то там фигуры.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by promoscow on 14.05.17.
 * Main activity for timer frame.
 */

public class Timer extends Fragment {

    DrawView drawView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        DrawView drawView = new DrawView(getActivity());
//        getActivity().setContentView(drawView);
        Log.d("Timer.onCreate", String.valueOf(getActivity()));
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Timer.onCreateView", String.valueOf(inflater));
        drawView = new DrawView(getActivity());
        return drawView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("onActivityCreated", "okay");
    }

    private class DrawView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private DrawThread drawThread;

        public DrawView(Activity timer) {
            super(timer);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Log.d("DrawView.surfaceChanged", "okay");
            drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder());
            drawThread.setRunning(true);
            drawThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            drawThread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    drawThread.join();
                    retry = false;
                    Log.d("DrawView.surfDestroyed", "okay");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class DrawThread extends Thread {
        private boolean running = false;
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        Paint paint;
        Rect rect;
        RectF rectF;
        Path path;

        public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            this.surfaceHolder = holder;
            paint = new Paint();
            rect = new Rect();
            path = new Path();
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
            Log.d("DrawThread.setRunning", "okay");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("DrawThread.run", "okay");
            Canvas canvas;
            while (running) {
            canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    if (canvas == null) continue;
                canvas.drawRGB(0, 100, 55);
                paint.setARGB(50, 56, 90, 124);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                canvas.drawRect(rectF, paint);
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                canvas.drawArc(rectF, 10, 10, false, paint);
                Log.d("DrawThread.run", "onWork");
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Логи вот такие:

```
05-14 22:26:02.158 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/Timer.onCreate: ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.StopWatchActivity@2928c3c3
05-14 22:26:02.158 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/Timer.onCreateView: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater@15998504
05-14 22:26:02.160 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/resX: 1440
05-14 22:26:02.160 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/resY: 2392
05-14 22:26:02.160 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/calcDP: 350.0
05-14 22:26:02.160 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/density: 3.5
05-14 22:26:02.160 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/heightPixels: 2392
05-14 22:26:02.160 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/widthPixels: 1440
05-14 22:26:02.160 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/dpHeight: 683.4286
05-14 22:26:02.160 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/dpWidth: 411.42856
05-14 22:26:02.161 14610-14610/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/onActivityCreated: okay
```

То есть, отрабатываются методы `onCreate` и `onCreateView`, потом отрабатываются методы активити, в котором находится фрагмент (высчеты dp и проч), потом отрабатывает `onActivityCreated` и всё...

Помогите, пожалуйста, желательно кодом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще если присмотреться, то Вы не проинициализировали переменную `RectF rectF`, но активно используете её в блоке `try-finally`. Я бы сделал ставку на то, что у Вас выпадает `NullPointerException`, но оно перехватывается этим блоком.

А вообще пока не понятно зачем столько сложностей. Зачем использовать `SurfaceView` вместе со всеми вытекающими проблемами?

Вот пример кода прямого наследника `View`, с тем же функционалом (были убраны неиспользуемые переменные) + регулировкой FPS:

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    private static final long FPS = 25;
    private static final long TIME_DELAY = 1000 / FPS;

    private final Runnable mInvalidator = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public final void run() {
            invalidate();
        }
    };

    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    {
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }
    private final RectF mRectF = new RectF();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                    int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected final void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRGB(0, 100, 55);
        mPaint.setARGB(50, 56, 90, 124);
        canvas.drawRect(mRectF, mPaint);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawArc(mRectF, 10, 10, false, mPaint);
        postDelayed(mInvalidator, TIME_DELAY);
    }
}
```

`FPS` в данном случае, это предпочитаемое `FPS`, совпадение с которым зависит от нагруженности UI. Если что-то более тяжелое планируется, то лучше использовать `Bitmap`, который будет подготавливаться в другом потоке, после чего выполнять отрисовку методом`canvas.drawBitmap(...)`.

Comment: Фантастика! Действительно, теперь вроде как всё ок. Меня заинтересовал код: `        {
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        }` До сих пор не сталкивался с таким способом задать характеристики переменной. Или это статическая инициализация? (давно не возвращался к ней) Можете прокомментировать? И ещё. В каком методе прописывается логика графики? (ну, там, изменение координат и проч.)

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов это **не**статический блок инициализации. Обычно выношу в него настройки переменных, которые применяю один раз и навсегда и которые нельзя задать в конструкторе. В данном случае вынес в него настройки кисти `Paint`, которые в Вашем коде применяются единожды. А статический блок инициализации начинается со `static { ... }`. Что касается логики графики, то это слишком общий вопрос. Из метода `onDraw` можете вызывать любой метод, но следите, чтобы в итоге не создавалось новых переменных внутри метода `onDraw`.

Comment: Точно. А то статический блок инициализации прошёл, а нестатический — нет. Спасибо!

Comment: @Artilirium, подскажите пожалуйста: если прорисовка идёт секунду, нельзя никак во View её делать в другом потоке? В Вашем решении разговор коснулся FPS'a в контексте View, что натолкнуло на мысль возможности реализации этого.

Comment: @EgorRandomize максимум, что можно сделать, как я уже написал, подготовить `Bitmap` в другом потоке для его последующей отрисовки на экране. Сама отрисовка всегда происходит в главном потоке. А попытка рисовать на `Canvas` вне главного потока приведёт к падению, потому что этот `Canvas` продолжает использоваться андроидом для отрисовки вышележащих на нём элементов.

Comment: @Artilirium, мне нужно плавно нарисовать линию на экране. Пытался прибегнуть к OpenGLES, но ничего из этого не вышло. Можете посоветовать, какой элемент управления использовать?

Comment: @EgorRandomize плавная отрисовка линии звучит достаточно обычно. Возможно Вам хватило бы стандартной анимации средствами Андроида.

Comment: Спасибо вам! Решил данный вопрос. Тестирую качество реализации моей задачи в ListView. При скроллинге нескольких элементов ListView подвисает, показывает полный ужас, чёрные дыры на холсте несколько кадров. Можем продолжить общение в ВК?

Comment: @EgorRandomize меня нет в ВК и других соцсетях :) Можете создать вопрос на `StackOverflow`, а тут в комментарии оставить ссылку на него, я попробую помочь) Если приведете примеры кода, то попробую помочь и в оптимизации)